# Как на динамичном прогресс-баре показывать процент выполнения?

Tags: python, bootstrap, progress-bar

В тегах `meter` работает, но там нет возможности показывать % заполнения на самом прогресс-баре.

Как на динамичном прогресс-баре показывать процент выполнения, `Bootstrap + python`?

Делаю расчеты в views

```
object['meter'] = []
if i.end_start1 > dt:
  object['meter'].append(100 - ((i.end_start1-dt).total_seconds()/(i.end_start1-i.start_data1).total_seconds())*100)
else:
  object['meter'].append(100)
```

Передаю в html

```
<td>
  {% if i.met1 != '9999' %}
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{ i.meter.0 }}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу:

```
for i in range(len(object['meter'])):
  object['meter'][i] = round(object['meter'][i])
```

и дивами в html:

```
<td>
  {% if i.met1 != '9999' %}
  <div style='width: 50px; background-color: white; height: 25px;'>
    {{ i.meter.0 }}%
    <div style='width: {{ i.meter.0 }}%; background-color: green; height: 25px; margin-top: -24px;'>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
</td>
```